# Python PYDBLITE - error adding records to pydblite

Tags: python, python-db-api

I have a Python script that uses the `pydblite` database library. when I run the code once the database is created and records added.  if I run the code again an error is generated..Help

Code

```
db = Base('Storys.pdl')
db.create('FeatureID', 'StoryID', 'Passed', 'Failed', 'Unexecuted', 'Deferred', 'Blocked', mode="open")    
db.insert("123", "456", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
db.insert("123", "456", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
db.commit()
print len(db)
for r in db:
    print r
    print db.exists()
```

error on second running;

```
 File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pydblite\pydblite.py", line 277, in insert
AttributeError: '_BasePy2' object has no attribute 'field_values'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug which has been fixed in version 3.0.1. See the [changelog](http://pydblite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/changelog.html)